# Memory Error with function calling large parameters

Tags: python, memory

THE PROGRAM:

This is a program that attempts to create a gibberish statement after being given a list of starting words of a sentence (seedBank) and a dictionary of word pairs (pairs) which contains information from a text file as to which words follow which.

An example for a text.txt file containing 'This is a cat. He is a dog.' would mean we would input the following:

```
seedBank = ['This', 'He']

pairs = { 'This':['is'],'is':['a','a'],'a':['cat','dog'],'He':['is'] }
```

Therefore the function uses these inputs to create a random generated sentence that makes vague sense as it follows a semi-grammatically correct format.

```
def gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs):
    gibSentence = []
    gibSentence.append(random.choice(seedBank)) #random seed
    x = gibSentence[0]
    while(pairs.get(x)is not None): #Loop while value x is a key in the dictionairy
        y = random.choice(pairs.get(x)) #random value of key x
        gibSentence.append(y) #random value is added to main string
        x = y #key x is reset to y
    return ' '.join(gibSentence) #String
```

THE PROBLEM:

This program works fine for passing small sentences like the one above with a set defined random.seed(value), however it fails and returns a memory error when given a set of inputs (seedBank and pairs) that are exceedingly large. My question is therefore what problems with this program could potentially cause it to have problems processing larger parameters?

Note these parameters are not in fact massive, i don't have the text document but it wouldn't be too big as to not have enough RAM for example.

Error code:

[image]

Thank you so much.

RESOLVED: Thank you! the problem is solved and it was in fact the while condition that was causing issues, this being that it loops through entire texts rather than just ending when it gets to a word that has a fullstop or question mark etc. Essentially this caused it to overload the memory, but thank you to everyone here for helping!

Comment: How big is the text file? On the order of KB? MB? GB? Also, I think we need to see the calling code -- my bet is that you're accidentally making copies of things that take up a huge amount of memory.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an automated testing system but i have emailed the person who supplied me the test so i can manually check it, I think the issue may be related to an infinite loop as mentioned below but i will take that into account.

The text file is only 9.5KB so something is going very wrong!

Comment: Thank you! the problem is solved and it was in fact the while condition that was causing issues, this being that it loops through entire texts rather than just ending when it gets to a word that has a fullstop or question mark etc.

Essentially this caused it to overload the memory, but thank you to everyone here for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your actual `pairs` it's hard to tell, but there is a possibility of an infinite loop if all of the words reference each other at some point:

```
pairs = { 'someone':['thinks'],'thinks':['that','how'],'that':['someone','anyone'],'how':['someone'], 'anyone': ['thinks'] }
```

will never finish.

Comment: This is a valid point that i hadn't thought of, as the function only wants to generate one sentence it should finish when the word has a . or ? or ! as it's last character therefore i may need to add in a test case for this.

Unfortunately this is an output from an automated testing system and i don't have the word_pairs_bank myself :/

Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Tim Pietzcker, your code can loop forever if there's a cycle in `pairs`. Here's the most basic example of that:

```
>>> seedBank = ['and']
>>> pairs = {'and': ['on'], 'on': ['and']}
>>> gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs)  # just keeps going
```

You can make sure your generated sentences will (eventually) end by modifying your `pairs` dict so that it includes a sentinel value when the word occurs as the last one in a sentence. for instance for a source text like 'You and me and the dog.':

```
seedBank = ['You']

pairs = {
    'You': ['and'],
    'and': ['me', 'the'],
    'me': ['and'],
    'the': ['dog'],
    'dog': ['.'],
}
```

... and adding a check for the sentinel in `gibberish_sentence()`:

```
def gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs):
    gibSentence = []
    gibSentence.append(random.choice(seedBank)) #random seed
    x = gibSentence[0]
    while(pairs.get(x)is not None): #Loop while value x is a key in the dictionairy
        y = random.choice(pairs.get(x)) #random value of key x
        if y == '.':
            break
        gibSentence.append(y) #random value is added to main string
        x = y #key x is reset to y
    return ' '.join(gibSentence) #String
```

... which gives the sentence a chance to terminate:

```
>>> gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs)
'You and the dog'
>>> gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs)
'You and me and me and me and me and me and the dog'
>>> gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs)
'You and me and the dog'
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining a list of strings isn't the worst, but it isn't the best in terms of space-efficiency.

Consider using something like [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) (untested, of course):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import random

def gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs):
    seed = random.choice(seedBank)
    gibSentence = StringIO()
    gibSentence.write(seed)             #random seed
    gibSentence.write(' ')
    x = seed
    while(pairs.get(x) is not None):    #Loop while value x is a key in the dictionairy
        y = random.choice(pairs.get(x)) #random value of key x
        gibSentence.write(y)            #random value is added to main string
        gibSentence.write(' ')
        x = y                           #key x is reset to y
    return gibSentence.getvalue() #String
```

[Here's a comparison](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/) of different string concatenation methods, in terms of operations per second and memory consumption.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response!

Yeah sorry i'm pretty new to Python syntax so i'm really just learning the ropes, i don't think this particular issue is caused by concatenation but thanks for the efficiency tips!

Answer (score 0):

Building a list can be avoided by using generators which are very memory efficient.

```
def gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs):
    x = random.choice(seedBank)) #random seed
    yield x
    while(pairs.get(x)is not None): #Loop while value x is a key in the dictionairy
        y = random.choice(pairs.get(x)) #random value of key x
        yield y
        x = y #key x is reset to y

print ' '.join(gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs)) #String
```

Or the string has to be built within the function, can be done this way,

```
def gibberish_sentence(seedBank, pairs):
    def words():
        x = random.choice(seedBank)) #random seed
        yield x
        while(pairs.get(x)is not None): #Loop while value x is a key in the dictionairy
        y = random.choice(pairs.get(x)) #random value of key x
        yield y
        x = y #key x is reset to y
    return ' '.join(words()) #String
```